# httpParams remove undefined params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to send params in my URL to get filtered data from the server.

I set params like this

```
const queryParams = new HttpParams(
      {
        fromObject: {
          page: this.paginator.pageIndex.toString(),
          pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize.toString(),
          search: this.searchKey,
          sortBy: this.selectedFilterByStatusValue,
          sortByType: this.selectedFilterSortByValue
        }
      });
```

And in my service

```
 getData(params: HttpParams) {
    return this.apiService.get<IResponseList<IData>>(`${this.url}/list`, params);
  }
```

Problem is, when some filter is not selected, because I don't need them, and it is set like undefined, but this is not correct... I need to remove undefined params.

Here is `console.log` for `queryParams`

```
cloneFrom: null
encoder: HttpUrlEncodingCodec {}
map: Map(5)
  [[Entries]]
  0: {"page" => Array(1)}
  1: {"pageSize" => Array(1)}
      key: "pageSize"
      value: ["3"]
  2: {"search" => Array(1)}
  3: {"sortBy" => Array(1)}
  4: {"sortByType" => Array(1)}
```

I try to use `.set("page", this.paginator.pageIndex)` and also `.append(...)` but I always get same structure

Also, I try directly in service fix this, but this not working, I again get `undefined`

```
this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/list`, { 
  params: Object.entries(queryParameterObject).reduce((queryParams, [key, value]) => queryParams.set(key, value), new HttpParams());
});
```

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to skip them in the `reduce`.

```js
this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/list`, { 
  params: queryParameterObject ? queryParameterObject.keys().reduce((queryParams, key) => {
  // getting value from map
  let value: any = queryParameterObject.get(key);

  // extracting value if it's an array
  value = Array.isArray(value) ? value[0] : value;

  // adding only defined values to the params
  if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
    queryParams[key] = value;
  }

  return queryParams;
}, {}) : {};
});
```

Comment: thnx, now I get this error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: Ah, might you try with `return queryParams.set(key, value);` in the `if`? On which line does it fail?

Comment: they fail on this line ` params: Object.entries(queryParameterObject).reduce((queryParams, [key,value]... `

Comment: ah, it means `queryParameterObject` doesn't exist, I've added the wrapper to handle this case.

Comment: thnx, they fix errors...but I dont't get my params from map. My URL now look like this `list?updates=null&cloneFrom=null&encoder=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&map=%5Bobject%20Map%5D` instead of `list?page=0&pageSize=3&search=string&sortByType=desc`

Comment: updated, now nulls are gone too, I think you don't need HttpParams at all, please try and let me know if it works. Also what is the value of `encoder`? looks like it's an object, how do you want to pass it to the backend? as json?

Comment: but problem here is, pls take a look at my example, I need in URL params from map because `httpParams` set this to map object, but with this I get wrong data, i get root data from `httpParams`

Comment: the map is an array of the values, how do you want this array to be sent? page=1, or page=[1], or page[]=1?

Comment: i need like this `?page=0&pageSize=3&search=string&sortByType=desc`

Comment: this is great. Only one more issue, in my filter I send, let say NAME, your code cut it and send only first letter...

Comment: Excellent... Thank you... now everything is working :)

Comment: can you also, if you have some time, little explain what are you done here. Thnx

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one-liner that I think might work for you :

```js
const newQueryParameterObject = Object.entries(queryParameterObject).reduce(
    (acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, ...((value != null) & { [key]: value }) }),
    {}
);

this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/list`, { params: new HttpParams({fromObject:newQueryParameterObject}) });
```

It will clean the variables with null or undefined values.

Comment: Thnx, can you pls implement this in my example? Because, when I try to put this like this `this.httpClient.get(`${this.url}/list`, { params: Object.keys(queryParameterObject).forEach(key => !queryParameterObject[key] ? delete queryParameterObject[key] : {})  }` I get in editor warning for params `No overload matches this call`

Comment: updated my answer. it just cleans the raw object before you create httpParams.

Comment: for first line in ur answer i get error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` and also this error `Cannot delete property 'updates' of [object Object]`

Answer (score 2):

Automatically stripping out undefined params using an interceptor or some kind of catch-all could lead to hidden bugs. For example, if you didn't handle that a variable could be undefined, it will silently remove the property from your request altogether and the bug/error will go unhandled. You'd have to inspect the request body when debugging to figure out what happened.

This begs the question, what SHOULD we do if a param value is `undefined`? According to most REST APIs, query params are optional, but to your front end the answer may be that you require their use for this call.

1. If it's undefined but required by your front-end, maybe we should actually treat that like an error and not make the request at all. In that case we'd just type check the variable and do some conditional logic.

```js
if (myparam === undefined) {
    // my app requires the use of this query param!
    alert('Something is wrong!');
    // handle the issue
    return;
}
```

2. If it's undefined but **optional**, then the following spread solution makes it really obvious and is a good solution.

This solution can prevent undefined params being passed in, and make it obvious at the call site that undefined values will not be included in the request:

```js
const myParamA = undefined;
const myParamB = 'foo';
this.http.get(someUrl, {
    params: {
        ...(myParamA === undefined ? {} : { myParamA }),
        ...(myParamB === undefined ? {} : { myParamB }),
    },
})
```

We make use of the spread operator to either spread in our object with our param, or we spread in an empty object (i.e. don't add any properties). In the above example `params` will be `{ myParamB: 'foo' }`.